# Cmd +z NOT working in sheets containing Excel Range or Table

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an Excel add-in using the JavaScript APIs to build add-ins in Excel Office 365.[ Mac ] 
Undo [ Cmd + z ] is not working on the sheets where I have results from a Excel table or Range . Is this a known issue ? If there is any workaround, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a behavior, with currently no workaround.  Essentially, any write operation done via the API clears the undo stack.  This has been true for Excel ever since its inception; VBA and COM/VSTO operations in Excel have the same undo-stack-clearing behavior.

Your feedback is appreciated, however, and -- making no promises or timeline statements -- I will say that it is an area we are actively investigating, to see if we could preserve the undo stack after all.  But it's a tremendous amount of work to support it in Excel, so it's not something that will happen overnight [if it happens at all].

By the way, I should note that Word does offer undo support; it's only Excel that has historically always blown away the undo stack when performing any object-model operations.